# trouble in converting Generic List coming from a WCF Service to a DataTable

Tags: datatable, wcf, generic-list

I am confused on how can I use generic methods to parse generic list into datatable/dataset. My setup:
1. I have a class Customers defined in WCF Service Library.

```
namespace Wcf.Sample.ServiceLibrary
{
    public class Customers
    {
        public string ID = string.Empty;
        public string CompanyName = string.Empty;
        public string ContactName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

2. I use this class to return a generic list from my OperationContract.

```
namespace Wcf.Sample.ServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustomerService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Customers> GetAllCustomers();
    }       
}
```

3. Consume WCF Service in web client page. On button click I populate the GridView with the list returned from GetAllCustomers(). This works perfectly fine.

```
GridView1.DataSource = client.GetAllCustomers();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

4. Now the issue is, for some reason (sort/paging function) I want to actually convert the returned generic list into a datatable. To do so, I have a method that returns me a datatable which I want to bind to a GridView. Here are the methods:

```
public static DataTable ConvertTo<T>(System.Collections.Generic.List<T> genericList)
{
    //create DataTable Structure
    DataTable dataTable = CreateTable<T>();
    Type entType = typeof(T);
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entType);
    //get the list item and add into the list
    foreach (T item in genericList)
    {
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return dataTable;
}

public static DataTable CreateTable<T>()
{
    //T –> ClassName
    Type entType = typeof(T);
    //set the datatable name as class name
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(entType.Name);
    //get the property list
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entType);
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
    {
        //add property as column
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

I am not sure how to call this function? How can I specify the  as Customers class which is actually in a webservice? Totally lost. I would appreciate if someone can guide me on the following code, how to make it work.

```
GridView1.DataSource = ConvertTo<???>(client.GetAllCustomers());
```

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking... you cannot use the type that you have on the other side. you can declare a similar type on the client and use that.

Comment: So you are saying it is not possible to convert the list returned from my service with cusotmers type? Can you tell me if there is another way to do so keeping in mind that I can't change the service.

Comment: i would create a similar type on the client and use that.

Comment: i think visual studio can create the client side version of the Customers class for you if you point it to the service. when you add a service reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by modifing the WCF Service itself (although I was reluctant to do so). I modified the GetAllCustomers method to return a datatable instead of generic type. In the service itself, I am converting the generic type into datatable using the same methods:

```
public static DataTable ConvertTo<T>(System.Collections.Generic.List<T> genericList) 
{ 
    //create DataTable Structure 
    DataTable dataTable = CreateTable<T>(); 
    Type entType = typeof(T); 
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entType); 
    //get the list item and add into the list 
    foreach (T item in genericList) 
    { 
        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow(); 
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties) 
        { 
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item); 
        } 
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row); 
    } 
    return dataTable; 
} 

public static DataTable CreateTable<T>() 
{ 
    //T –> ClassName 
    Type entType = typeof(T); 
    //set the datatable name as class name 
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(entType.Name); 
    //get the property list 
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entType); 
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties) 
    { 
        //add property as column 
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType); 
    } 
    return dataTable; 
}
```

Another thing that I noticed is that the following line

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entType);
```

would always returned null for my type. This was due to the fact that I didn't have any get/set methods in Customers class. I created get/set methods in Customer class and everything worked like a charm.

Thanks to everyone who helped and those who tried to help :)